# IntelliJ Java edit .jsp no server restart

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm a front-end web developer and have been given a Java project where my task is to develop the front-end .jsp files (html / css / js).

I have setup the project in IntelliJ community edition 15 and it runs fine using Maven:

```
mvn -Denv=local tomcat7:run-war
```

Only it takes 1 min and 30 seconds to compile and it is frustrating to wait that long just to see a simple CSS / HTML change.

I was informed that it is possible with IntelliJ to set it up in a way so I can edit the .jsp files and see the change on the fly without restarting tomcat.

But how? (as you might have guessed I know very little about Java / Maven / Tomcat)

I got this Maven window in IntelliJ looking like below:

[image]

And also a POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hermes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hermes</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <org.springframework.amqp.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.amqp.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.0</jackson.version>
        <google.simple.spring.memcached.version>3.6.0</google.simple.spring.memcached.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
            <version>${google.simple.spring.memcached.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>spymemcached-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${google.simple.spring.memcached.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dbcore-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-driver-oracle11g</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kevinsawicki</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-request</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rabbit/JMS/AMQP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.xxxx.net</id>
            <url>http://maven.xxxx.net:8080/artifactory/libs-releases-local/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring libs milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Couchbase</id>
            <url>http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenrepository.com</id>
            <url>repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Milestone Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>plugins-releases</name>
            <url>http://maven.xxxx.net:8080/artifactory/plugins-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots />
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>plugins-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.xxxx.net:8080/artifactory/plugins-snapshots</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>hermes</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/spring</directory>
                                    <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.xxxx.hermes.app.Hermes</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>.java</resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Useful for purging local repository and re-downloading all dependencies 
                in event of major/minor version conflicts -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8891</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/classes/com/xxxx/**/*.java,WEB-INF/lib/servlet*.jar
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What framework are you using? Also, checkout https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: Also, most cases you can compile resources. On Windows or Linux, Ctrl+F9 then Ctrl+F10 will build.

Comment: It uses Spring. Check the POM file I just posted. Thanks.

Comment: Spring 4 supports HotSwapping as well https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Are you developing JSP or html/css/js?

Comment: Intellij has wonderful integration with Tomcat if you purchase the Ultimate edition. Then you can update your JSP deployment instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that you have Community edition. If you were to upgrade to the Ultimate edition, then you could

1. Enable your Intellij to deploy to Tomcat. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/defining-application-servers-in-intellij-idea.html
2. Create a Run Configuration for your **hermes** web application. Click Run menu, Edit Configurations menu item. Click the [+] button to add a configuration. Select Tomcat Server, Local.
3. Click the Deployment Tab.
4. Under the **Deploy at server startup** section, click [+] to add a deployment. Choose **hermes:war exploded**[image]
5. Click [Ok]
6. Now in the Run menu, click Debug. This will launch your hermes web application in Tomcat with debug running.
7. Edit a JSP file.
8. Now in the Run menu, click **Update 'Unnamed' Application**. In the **Update 'Unnamed'** dialog, choose 'Update Resources' and [Ok]. This will redeploy your JSP change. Note there are shortcuts for this. In my IntelliJ I can press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quickly redeploy the change.

[image]

Comment: Amazing Kirby. Thanks alot. I took your advice and got IntelliiJ full edition, followed your steps and it works as one would expect :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "run-war" goal was used. It runs the "packaged" version of the app. Try running:

```
tomcat7:run
```

(instaed of "run-war" - it's just one goal above in the window you've shown)
[Maven window in IntelliJ looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7GX2.png)

You may also need to add this to your dependencies in the pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.5</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

That has done the job for me: now I can easily edit the html / css / js files (on the fly) without the need of constant tomcat restart and redeploy.